# Is the list of the questions to ask/not to ask in the new about page sufficient?

Tags: discussion

The [about page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/about) has been changed, and it contains three parts that moderators can edit. Two of those sections are about the questions to ask, and the questions not to ask, which currently contain the following list:

- To ask

  - Specific issues with Drupal
  - Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered using Drupal
- Not to ask

  - Anything not directly related to Drupal
  - Requests for tutorials, and other online resources
  - Building a site from scratch
  - Questions that are primarily opinion-based
  - Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer

Is there anything else that needs to be added, considering that the about page is supposed to give the first information to who visit *Drupal Answers*? The page is not supposed to be exhaustive.

@[Shog9](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/885/shog9): Thank you for having provided that list.

Comment: I think the new about page is good and self explaining :-) Good job! I just earned a badge!

Comment: Love the new about page is simple and well explained... thanks